# Set String of ArrayList in Recyler view

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to set response from API in RecylerView in textview. But I'm not able to set below values

This is my response from API

```
{
  "message": "slot_time",
  "success": "200",
  "result": [
    {
      "morning": [
        "08:00AM",
        "08:30AM",
        "09:00AM",
        "09:30AM",
        "10:00AM",
        "10:30AM",
        "11:00AM",
        "11:30AM"
      ]     

    }
  ]
}
```

My main Activity Class

```
    private void getSlotes(String date) {

        GetDataService mGetDataService = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance(getApplicationContext()).create(GetDataService.class);
        SharedPref.init(AppConstant.FILENAME, getApplicationContext());
        String userID = SharedPref.getUserId(AppConstant.USER_ID, "");
        String type = SharedPref.getScheduleType(AppConstant.TYPE, "");
        String channelID = SharedPref.getChannelID(AppConstant.CHANNEL_ID, "");
        Call<SlotsResponse> call = mGetDataService.getSlots(userID, dID, channelID, type, date);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<SlotsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<SlotsResponse> call, @NonNull Response<SlotsResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        ArrayList<Result> morningList = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getResult().size(); i++) {
                            try {
                                morningList.add(response.body().getResult().get(i));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        mMorningAdapter = new MorningSlotAdapter(morningList, getApplicationContext());
                        mornigRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<SlotsResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here I'm trying to set value in Adapter Class but value is null

```
    public MorningSlotAdapter(ArrayList<Result> list, Context mContext) {
        this.list = list;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SlotViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.slotTime.setText(list.get(position).getMorning().get(position));
    }
```

I'm tried many way but doesn't work for me I'm stuck in this issue

Comment: How does the rest of your adapter class look like and where did you initialize the RecyclerView?

Comment: add your adapter code and try using GSON it will help you

Comment: Show your `SlotsResponse`class